# Can I see folder size in bitbucket repository?

Tags: bitbucket

I am struggling to find a way to see bitbucket FOLDER size. Repo size is easily accessible, but why doesn't BitBucket list folder sizes inside the repo? I can only see file sizes in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** , currently bitbucket doesn't allow (or support) to view `folder` size in bitbucket repository.

But as you have mentioned you can always view the `repo` size :

`Under Settings > Repository Details after clicking on "Retrieve Size Details".`